# Semantic UI not rendering Text

Tags: jquery, css, html, grid-layout, semantic-ui

I've got a pretty basic scaffold going, but for some reason, none of my text in `<p>` tags is showing. Could someone explain why? https://jsfiddle.net/h769p2wt/2/

I'm guessing the issue is due to some missing class in my structure. Is there a guide for setting-up a website to "be ready" for Semantic-UI? Am I supposed to use the `ui` class here? Any help with this would be tremendous!!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.0/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.0/semantic.min.js"></script>
<nav class="ui inverted fixed main menu">
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/" class="title brand item">StuffCo</a>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/" class="active item">Home</a>
    <div class="right menu">
        <a href="http://localhost:3000/contact" class="item">Contact</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<main class="ui page grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column center aligned starter">
            <div class="ui grid">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1>StuffCo</h1>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>Delivering Stuff to your Things</p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <p>Impressive Leading Statement</p>
                    <h2 id="service-offerings">Some header</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Why am I not visible?</li>
</ul></div></div></div></div></main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is your scaffolding structure.  Grids must have columns in them (though rows aren't necessary; see the [grid spec](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#/overview)).

You're missing a column in your second grid:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.0/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.0/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="ui inverted fixed main menu">
            <a href="http://localhost:3000/" class="title brand item">StuffCo</a>
            <a href="http://localhost:3000/" class="active item">Home</a>
            <div class="right menu">
                <a href="http://localhost:3000/contact" class="item">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main class="ui page grid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column center aligned starter">
                    <div class="ui grid">
                        <div class="row">
<!-- THIS WAS THE MISSING LINE --><div class="column center aligned">
                            <h1>StuffCo</h1>
                            <blockquote>
                                <p>Delivering Stuff to your Things</p>
                            </blockquote>
                            <p>Impressive Leading Statement</p>
                            <h2 id="service-offerings">Some header</h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Just kidding, now I'm visible</li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```